# Data backup/restore for Flutter

Tags: flutter, local-storage, backup, key-value

In flutter, how can you restore  key value data stored in shared preferences or secure storage when the app reinstalls? Is there any other library that can be used for small data backup/restore? Like retrieving user's selected theme: Light or Dark from the previous install. Unable to find somethin like this for flutter. Please help.

Comment: Beginning with Android 11, you can't do such things locally anymore.